# Ruby API wrapper and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, wrapper

Ok so, I've got a Ruby wrapper on a Gem form for some REST API, after installing the gem I can create Ruby files and, as long as I use `require 'gem_file_name"` everything works...

Now, I want to be able to use this gem on a Rails project so I can call the methods and display in different pages the results.
The gem, strictly speaking, is not being made to work with rails, can I still use it adding it to the Rails Gemfile?

The API requires a Token and an account number now, those are the problems...

1. I created in `config/initializers/` a file with the same gem_name.rb
   and on it there are two variables: the token and the account number.
   The actual values of those variable are in `config/local_env.yml` as env variables. Point is when I start the `rails s` I get an error: `Uninitialized constant.`
2. Assuming I manage to fix issue 1, would I be able to use the methods on the wrapper without using `require 'gem_file_name'` on each erb page?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Yep you can add a pure ruby gem to rails, since everything in the `Gemfile` is required by default you do not have to add the explicit require. But for 1) we need to see some actual code: that is all too vague.

Comment: it seems the problem is with the env variable. Creating the YAML file in `config/local_env.yml` path should I then be able to call the variable on the rails console? `API_TOKEN: very-long-string-with-the-token` using `ENV["API_TOKEN"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this is what I did:

1. Created a variable with the token on `config/secrets.yml` -> `api_token: verylongstring`
2. Added the `secrets.yml` file on `.gitignore`
3. Created a `before_action` in the controller I wanted to use the APIs to establish the connection and `Rails.application.secrets.api_token` to call the token variable from the `secrets.yml` file

Answer (score 0):

Rails provides the config/application.rb file for specifying settings for various Rails components. We want to set our environment variables before any other settings. Rails provides a config.before_configuration method to do so.

You need to add following code in config/application.rb to use the config/local_env.yml:

```
config.before_configuration do
     env_file = File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 'local_env.yml')
     YAML.load(File.open(env_file)).each do |key, value|
       ENV[key.to_s] = value
     end if File.exists?(env_file)
end
```

Comment: Thanks @lalit.sethi143 this cause an error when launching the rails server or console... `undefined local variable or method 'config' for main:Object (NameError)`

Comment: Please refer this post  http://railsapps.github.io/rails-environment-variables.html